# Create custom provider and link to web service

Tags: java, resteasy

I would like my web service to produce "text/csv".

I have included the maven dependency CsvSerializerProvider from apache.  It is a provider and produces "text/csv" as follows

```
@Provider
@Produces("text/csv")
public class CsvSerializerProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<CsvSerializer> {
}
```

Now in my webservice I @Produces("text/csv") like so

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, "text/csv"})
public class RecordREST {
}
```

When I use curl to try to hit my endpoint I get an error saying

```
Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: jaxb.JaxbList of media type: text/csv
```

I can get the .xml just fine since its standard but csv apparently this isn't linked properly.  How do I do so?

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that you are trying to write a `JaxbList`, but your `MessageBodyWriter` is configured to write an object of `CsvSerializer`.

If your method is returning a `JaxbList` and you want to have Resteasy convert that to a CSV you are going to need a `MessageBodyWriter` that handles `JaxbList`.

```
@Provider
@Produces("text/csv")
public class CsvSerializerProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<JaxbList> {
}
```

Ideally your method on your web service would return a domain object, `Foo`, that would be annotated with JAXB annotations in your case and then your `CsvSerializerProvider` would look like the following:

```
@Provider
@Produces("text/csv")
public class CsvSerializerProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<Foo> {
}
```

Also you need to make sure that your provider is being registered with Resteasy:

- If you are running in JBoss AS7 `@Provider` annotation scanning is handled automatically without any extra configuration
- If you are bootstrapping your service with a subclass of `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` then you can register your providers in your Application subclass.

> ```
> public class MyApplication extends Application
> {
>   private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
>
>   public MyApplication() 
>   { 
>       singletons.add(new MyCustomMessageBodyWriter());
>       singletons.add(new MyResource());
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public Set<Object> getSingletons()
>   { 
>       return singletons;
>   }
> }
> ```

- If you are starting your service as a servlet with `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher` then you need to tell Resteasy to automatically scan for `@Provider` annotations by setting the `resteasy.scan` or `resteasy.scan.providers` context parameters to `true` in your `web.xml`.

> ```
> <context-param>
>    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
>    <param-value>true</param-value>
> </context-param>
> ```

- If you are using Spring to register your Resteasy resources with `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener` then you can tell Spring to scan them by adding an `includeFilter` to `ComponentScan`.

> ```
> @ComponentScan(value = "com.foo", 
>                includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Provider.class))
> ```

Comment: I have changed my method to implement MessageBodyWriter<JaxbList>. I am bootstrapping the service with a subclasss of Application but my provider is still not found. However, I have my extension of Application currently blank.

Comment: @Cam Sonaris - I have edited my answer. I'm sorry, but I may have misinterpreted the docs for javax.ws.rs.core.Application. I was under the impression that auto-scanning happened automatically, but per the latest docs it appears that you need to register them by hand as I have shown above or use the resteasy.scan context parameter.

Comment: Thank you. However now I am getting an error "Could not find resource for relative /my/path/ of full path /my/full/path"

Comment: @Cam Sonaris - You will need to add your resource classes to that set as well.  I assumed you were already doing that since you were subclassing Application.

Comment: im confused what you mean by adding my resource classes to that set.  Which set?

Comment: @Cam Sonaris - Take a look at bullet point 2 above.  There is a set called singletons where I am adding providers and resource classes.  More info here:  http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.1.Final/userguide/html_single/#javax.ws.rs.core.Application